# Azure AD authentication on Windows App using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, windows, adal.js

I'm working on a windows app using pure JavaScript and try to use AAD for authentication. The issue that I'm facing is aftering calling the "login" function from adal.js which will redirect user to the login page, how shall the app receive the response assuming the user logged in successfully? The page that I'm seeing now after login is saying"This page cannot be displayed. Make sure the web address https://login.microsoftonline.com  is correct." I have entered the redirectURI value in azure with the one starting with "ms-app://s-1-15-***".

I've gone through the examples from the [AAD developer's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-developers-guide) and I don't see examples of windows app + pure JavaScript. The "Windows Universal" section has example of C# and the "JavaScript" section is for web page application.

Answer (score 0):

As adal for js is designed for web application, the `redirect_url` parameter requires a web server host location. So the using plain javascript to integrate adal for js is not so suitable in this scenario.

You can try to follow several workarounds:

- To use C# lib in your UWP application.
- To use Azure Mobile Apps' Authentication feature to authenticate & authorize your users. On sever side, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-users. And on your UWP side, you can refer to https://yorkporc.wordpress.com/2014/06/07/winjs-windows-store-app-and-aad-sso-experience-i-e-save-cookies-from-microsoftonlineaad-login-pages/ for similar usage.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I'm trying to use this method: Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAsync(option, startUrl, endUrl)

This method will basically create a popup to allow user to log in. I'm able to type in my credentials. But then after signing in, it shows "Can't connect to the service". Any idea what could cause the issue? I tried to open the startUrl from the browser and it works fine.

Comment: In windows apps, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devquickstarts-windowsstore for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to perform the AAD authentication in windows app using javascript. So there's the WebAuthenticationBorker from WinRT that can be utilized for the authentication through the OAuth2 endpoint.
A link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883954.aspx) is a very helpful example.